# How to upload image in database using jqgrid with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with asp.net 4.0 web form application and I just want to upload image into sqlserver database. Please suggest what is right way with example. Thanks in advance.

```
     colModel: [
            { name: 'imageToUpload', index: 'ImageID', align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'file', editoptions: { enctype: "multipart/form-data" }, search: false },
                                          }
                                ],

                                 beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid) {
                                    var complete = false;
                                    var message = "";
                                    var namefile = "";
                                    alert("hi");
                                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                                        url: '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Master/PolicyMaster.ashx") %>',
                                        secureuri: false,
                                        fileElementId: 'imageToUpload',
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function (data, status) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                   return [true, message];
                                },
```

Comment: You will not get any decent answers because you did not show what you tried.